# Replicate jQuery code in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have such sort of code in jQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
 if($('.element').hasClass('active')){       
    $('.element').removeClass('active'); 
 }
 else{
    $('.element').addClass('active');
 }
});
```

What would be the analogue of such code in Angular2. I suppose I have to put that in to related component. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

According to the `expression`'s value, which is true or false `active` class is removed and added. To learn more go to [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html)

```
<div [ngClass]="{active:expression}"></div
```

Answer (score 0):

Read and set the class with `@Input()` and `@HostBinding()

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sub-ele',
  template: `
  <div>hasActiveClass: {{hasActive}}</div>
  <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>
`
})
export class MyComponent {
  // read all classes from the DOM
  @Input('class') classes;

  // reflect the hasActive state to the DOM
  @HostBinding('class.active') hasActive = false;

  toggle() {
    this.hasActive = !this.hasActive;  
  }

  // initialize the `hasActive` state
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hasActive = this.classes && 
        this.classes.split(' ').indexOf('active') != -1;
  }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pYOsDt?p=preview)